# z-index only applies to previous children?

Tags: css, z-index

I have this bar graph made with html/css/jquery, when you hover a bar you get more info. This "pop up" only gets on top of the previous bars but no the following ones?
Why?

HTML

```
<li>
    <div style='height:87%' class='graphs'>
        <span class='info'>2014-05-07 downloads: 461</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS

```
#bars li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}

#bars li .graphs{
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0 1px 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32CD32 0%, #228B22 100%);
    background-clip: content-box;
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display:none;       
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
     transition: opacity 1s ease-in;        
    z-index:1;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}

#bars li .graphs:hover{
    -webkit-transition: margin-bottom 1s,opacity 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 1s;  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: margin-bottom 1s, opacity 1s ease-out, transform 1s;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;

}
#bars li .graphs span.info{
    display:none;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    background-color:rgba(240, 232, 232, 0.9);
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:-100px;
    z-index:3;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0 1px 3px;
}
```

More info here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4PNmD/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of #bar's li children share the same z-index. So as they're being added in the DOM, they're seemingly stacking on top of one another semantically. You could add

```
#bars li:hover {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

to get it function properly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to each one of your `li`'s establishing its own stacking context. `z-index` only is used for elements within the same context.

The reason that the box appears above bars to the left of its own bar, and is hidden under bars to the right, is because ordering comes into play. The `li`'s are in the same stacking context - the children across `li`'s are not! And since the `li`'s all have the same `z-index`, the specification indicates that the order of the elements determine which element gets stacked over the other.

ref: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/